# Are there ways to use inline keyboard and comment button together?

Tags: javascript, api, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot that sends a message to a channel. I want to implement the button attached to this post (`inline keyboard button`), but I also want to see the `comment` button. When you add an `inline keyboard`, it disappears.


`Comments` button:

[image: Example #1]

`Inline Keyboard Button` (the text doesn't matter):

[image: Example #2]

**Code Example without keyboard (Golang):**

```
message := tgbotapi.NewPhotoUpload(channel.ID, tgbotapi.FileBytes{
    Name:  "image-name",
    Bytes: image,
})
message.Caption = "This is the caption"
message.ParseMode = "HTML"
response, err := bot.Send(message)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

**Code Example with keyboard (Golang):**

```
var keyboard = tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardMarkup(
    tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardRow(
        tgbotapi.NewInlineKeyboardButtonData("Test", "test"),
    ),
)
message := tgbotapi.NewPhotoUpload(channel.ID, tgbotapi.FileBytes{
    Name:  "image-name",
    Bytes: image,
})
message.Caption = "This is the caption"
message.ParseMode = "HTML"
message.ReplyMarkup = keyboard
response, err := bot.Send(message)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Is there any way to use these feautures together?

Answer (score 1):

You must create an inline URL button with a link, e.g.,

```
https://t.me/c/<groupId>/<groupMessageId + 1000000>?thread=<groupMessageId>
```

where `groupId` is the id of your group for comments, and `groupMessageId` is the id of message of your post in group for comments.

Comment: Thanks, but we have no id of the message in discussion chat when we create a new message in the channel...

Comment: @LennyLip, so you have to add your bot in discussion chat and parse messages from your channel

Comment: AFAIK, the bots can't get messages lists, also GetDiscussionMessage method has been blocked for bots recently also.

Comment: @LennyLip, of course message can only be received when it has been sent. So you can not add comments button on older posts. Only from the moment the bot has been added.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler link for this.

```
https://t.me/<channelName>/<originalMessageId>?comment=1
```

where `channelName` - is username of your channel, `originalMessageId` is the id of the original message (not message id in the group for comments)

**update** It seems this is not working with messages with the inline keyboard (only with native comment button).

Answer (score 0):

You must create an inline URL button with a link, e.g.,

`https://t.me/<channelName>/<originalMessageId>?thread=<originalMessageId>`

where channelName - is username of your channel, originalMessageId is the id of the original message (not message id in the group for comments)